# USB Tethering internet connection not working

Tags: usb, internet, internet-connection

The internet connection seems to be not working when I tether my phone to my windows 7 PC, and it shows IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity to be not connected.

[image]

Comment: So just provide a link to the screenshot you uploaded to imgur

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/62yr7.jpg

Comment: Is this something that stopped working or is this the first time you are attempting to get it to work?

Comment: It stopped working a week ago, I googled a lot about it but couldn't find the solution for the specific problem.